# How to prove $|a+b|^n-|a|^n\geq C |b|^n+|a|^{n-2} a\cdot b$

Tags: analysis, inequality

I want to prove that there exists some constant $C=C(n)>0$, such that $|a+b|^n-|a|^n\geq C |b|^n+|a|^{n-2} a\cdot b$, where $n\geq 2$ is a positive integer and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. But I was trapped in the calculation process.

Here is my thought:

Firstly, restrict $C\leq 1$, then we know in both case $a=0$ and $b=0$, the inequality holds. So we assume that $a\cdot b\neq 0$. If $a\cdot b>0$, taking $C=1$ yields the desired inequality by the binomial expansion. If $a\cdot b<0$, we only need to prove
$$
 |1-x|^n-1\geq C\cdot x^n-x,\quad x>0.
 $$
However, when proving this inequality, I found that the derivative will change sign for more that one times when $n$ is large, and I didn't come up with the skills to prove it.

My question is, is this inequality really true (I believe it's true since it appeared in a classic article, but this article can't be retrieved on the internet, so I can't check it) and how to prove it.

Any help will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: Have you tried by induction?

Comment: @Falcon  Thanks for your help. But maybe induction method needs a known $C$. However, Bauval proves that such $C$ doesn't exist, so maybe we need some further restriction on $a$ and $b$. Whatever, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not exist such a $C>0,$ since for $b=-a\ne0,$ the inequality implies $-1\ge C-1.$